# jsp ldap single sign on

Tags: jsp, single-sign-on, openldap

I am working on an application (SSO with OpenLDAP and java). On authentication a user using SASL, I wish to retrieve userid/username with which one has logged in and take it to a new window on click of a tab in menu of my webpage. I have tried `getUsername()`, `session.getAttribute()`, `request.getParameter()` but it returns a `null`. 
Appears I am stuck, hoping for some guidance.

Comment: It would make it a lot easier to help you if you could post some snippets of the code that you are using.

Comment: Some formatting improvements.